# Why does `file -i` determines file encoding as ASCII, however it is UTF-8 actually in git repository

Tags: git, locale, encoding, utf-8, ascii

There are two cases, which i confused about:

1. If newly created file contains only latin symbols, then `file -i` will show `us-ascii`.
2. If newly created file contains only latin and cyrillic symbols, then `file -i` will show `utf-8`

I tested this behavior with several tools for creating files within local copy of git repository: intellij idea, nano, echo etc.

However, when i push this files to remote repository, participants on Windows OS determines this files as UTF-8.

Comment: us-ascii is a subset of utf-8. So this may not be so strange at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, since there is no BOM generated during file creation - there is no way to distinguish ASCII and UTF-8. So in terms of correct `prediction` of file encoding - it is better to answer ASCII, than UTF-8 (if both contains only latin characters), since UTF-8 involves more char-codes.

Therefore `file -i` doing all the best.

Thanks [fedonkadifeli](https://askubuntu.com/users/855322/fedonkadifeli) for the help.